# How to iterate over a file in python in a particular way as described below.

Tags: python

A file ProgramInput.txt has this as its content

```
<start>
content
...
...
...
<stop>

<start>
content
...
...
<stop>
```

and so on

How do I iterate over the txt file , so that I take out the content between each  and  and store it in a different file in each iteration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, I can think of it is

```
contents = []

with open('file') as f:
     for line in f:
         if line.startswith('<start>'):
            pass
         contents.append(line)

contents = "".join(contents)
sections = contents.split("<stop>")
```

Basically, make use of the pattern behavior and store in a list, and then use the pattern again to get the sections.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to extract text between the delimiters.